# Error during get Flavor list: java.lang.NullPointerException: URI template of the newly created target must not be null

Tags: jsf, openstack

I am using JSF to develop web application and also using OpenStack4J to work with OpenStack,
In my bean component I have method:

```
public List<SelectItem> getFlavorList() {

         List<SelectItem> items = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

         OSClient osClient = OSFactory.builder().endpoint("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000/v2.0")
            .credentials("admin", "nova").tenantName("admin").authenticate();

         List<? extends Flavor> flavors = osClient.compute().flavors().list();

         SelectItem item = null;
         for (Flavor flv: flavors){
              item = new SelectItem();
              item.setLabel(flv.getName());
              item.setValue(flv.getId());
         }
         items.add(item);

         return items;
    }
```

If i create a main test to test this method, everything ok, I can get the flavor list from OpenStack, but when i try to call from JSF page it appear a problem.

In My JSF page, I trying to call

```
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{dropletBean.droplet.flavorID}">
               <f:selectItem itemLabel="Please select one size" /> 
               <f:selectItems value="#{flavorBean.getFlavorList()}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
```

The error appear as below. Please help me to check it.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: URI template of the newly created target must not be null.
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:229)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:179)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:69)
at org.openstack4j.core.transport.internal.HttpExecutor.invoke(HttpExecutor.java:73)
at org.openstack4j.core.transport.internal.HttpExecutor.execute(HttpExecutor.java:52)
at org.openstack4j.core.transport.internal.HttpExecutor.execute(HttpExecutor.java:43)
at org.openstack4j.openstack.internal.BaseOpenStackService$Invocation.execute(BaseOpenStackService.java:136)
at org.openstack4j.openstack.internal.BaseOpenStackService$Invocation.execute(BaseOpenStackService.java:131)
at org.openstack4j.openstack.compute.internal.FlavorServiceImpl.list(FlavorServiceImpl.java:24)
at com.vdco.icloud.openstack.web.service.impl.FlavorServiceImpl.getFlavorIDList(FlavorServiceImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Thanks you so much

Comment: it looks like it is calling `FlavorServiceImpl.getFlavorIDList` method, not `getFlavorList` method that you mentioned. 
And you don't need to have parenthesis for getting list in jsf just '#{flavorBean.flavorList}` should do

Comment: Yes, you're right, because from my FlavorBean class, I've called getFlavorIDList () from FlavorServiceImpl.
I've try to call "#{flavorBean.getFlavorList}" without parenthesis but it's inform me error that "Property 'getFlavorList' not found "
"Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /create.xhtml @56,61 value="#{flavorBean.getFlavorList}": Property 'getFlavorList' not found on type com.vdco.icloud.openstack.web.servlet.jsf2.FlavorBean
"

Comment: as i mentioned in first comment, it should be ***#{flavorBean.flavorList}***. JSF will attach getters to them. you don't need to give exact method name there.